# Cannot filter rows based on tuple conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

| employe_id | skill_level | skill_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1550 | BEGINNER | 560 |
| 6540 | BEGINNER | 560 |
| 2354 | INTERMEDIATE | 560 |
| 6654 | ADVANCED | 560 |
| 1550 | ADVANCED | 780 |
| 6540 | BEGINNER | 780 |
| 1550 | INTERMEDIATE | 780 |
| 2354 | INTERMEDIATE | 780 |
| 1550 | INTERMEDIATE | 450 |
| 6540 | BEGINNER | 654 |
| 8888 | BEGINNER | 560 |
| 6654 | ADVANCED | 455 |
| 1550 | ADVANCED | 110 |
| 6540 | ADVANCED | 885 |
| 2354 | ADVANCED | 980 |
| 6654 | INTERMEDIATE | 870 |

I want to only get employees with specific skills and their specific respective levels; I would get something like this:

| employe_id | skill_level | skill_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1550 | BEGINNER | 560 |
| 1550 | INTERMEDIATE | 780 |

I tried this but obviously it's not what I want because it has an inclusive `OR`, so I don't know which operator / technique should I use

```
select * 
from employees_skills mec
where (mec.skill_id, mec.skill_level) = (560, 'BEGINNER') 
or (mec.skill_id, mec.skill_level) = (780, 'INTERMEDIATE')
```

If I do this for a set of two skills (and their resp. levels), I'll be able to do it for more.

**EDIT**: the employee 2354 should not be returned (even though they are beginner at 560, but they don't have the other skill 780 and/or they're not intermediate at it).

I expect employees who have ALL the skills in the WHERE conditions and their resp. levels

Answer (score 1):

You need some extra parens ():

```
SELECT * 
FROM employees_skills mec
WHERE ((mec.skill_id, mec.skill_level) = (560, 'BEGINNER'))
OR ((mec.skill_id, mec.skill_level) = (423, 'INTERMEDIATE'));
```

This creates a tuple and that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I have made a couple of mistakes. I have just adjusted my post and edited the table and the expected results. The query does not return what I expect

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is you are looking for the combination skill combination (423, 'INTERMEDIATE'), however that combination *does not exist in your data*.  
Your scenario presents an interesting dilemma: Your results must have multiple skill_id, skill_level combinations, but a single row can only have a single value set of skill_id, skill_level. So how to compare multiple rows to multiple values *at the same time*. Well you could use a series of `and exists (select ...)`. However, this requires knowing the number of combinations or dynamic sql to construct the exist clauses. Another, is to use array comparison, specifically the [array containment operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html)

> anyarray @> anyarray → boolean
> Does the first array contain the second, that is, does each element appearing in the second array equal some element of the first
> array?

First build UDT that containers both skill_id and skill_level. Then create a table (could be a temporary table) to contain an array of the UDT.

```
-- Create a UDT to contain both skill_id and skill_level
create type skill_level_t as (sk_id integer, sk_level text); 
    
-- create a work table to contain Arrays of target skill_id, skill_level combinations
 create table target_skills(tgt_skill_id integer generated always as identity
                                         primary key 
                           , skills      skill_level_t[]
                           );
```

With the above in place you now aggregate the employee skills set by employee. Then JOIN that aggregate to the target skills with the contains operator (`@>`). ([see demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/-jHmvnGL))

```
-- target query
select emp_id           "Employee Id" 
     , (slist).sk_level "Skill Level"
     , (slist).sk_id    "Skill Id" 
  from ( select emp_id, unnest(skills) slist 
           from ( select es.emp_id,ts.skills
                   from ( select emp_id, array_agg( (skill_id, skill_level )::skill_level_t) skills 
                            from emp_skills
                          group by emp_id
                        )  es
                   join target_skills ts 
                     on  es.skills @> ts.skills
                 ) sq1
        ) sq2;
```

NOTE: The final query can probably be refactored and reduced, but I wanted to show each step in its development.

---

EDIT on question: Isn't there a simpler / faster way?  
As I said it can probably be reduced. But look carefully you will see that the section  `( select es ... ) s1` is the only part actually accessing the database. The others are just simple transformations of the results from previous step that is already in memory thus requiring no actual additional i/o. As mentioned you could use a set of `and exists (select ...` but number of selects needed is the same as the number `(mec.skill_id, mec.skill_level)` criteria sets (5 criteria then 5 selects, 10 criteria then 10 selects, 50 criteria well you get the idea). Each accessing the database with likely additional i/o. The above does not change regardless of the number of criteria (5, 10, 50 the query remains the same). Also combining simple transformations can into a single large transform can get complicated very quickly, just stringing the together seldom works. Obviously my opinion but *isn't there a simpler/faster way?* **No**. One option may be to hide the query within a SQL function.

Comment: thank you, but isn't there a simpler / faster way? in you solution, there many nested queries, and I have thousands of rows in those table, this could take some time before I get to be able to return the result to the user

Comment: See EDIT section of answer.

Comment: If I will have to create a new table and a new table (I should not touch the schema), then do the cleanup for later queries, and also handle concurrent queries, I guess it's simpler to filter out the data programmatically